# PHP artisan migrate not works

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, artisan-migrate

this is my config details - it's 100% correct

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=bglee
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

the migrate file

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->char("name" , 80);
            $table->char("username" , 50)->primary();
            $table->char("email" , 50)->unique();
            $table->char("password",50);
            $table->char("phone",25)->unique();
            $table->char("country",40)->nullable();
            $table->char("government",40)->nullable();
            $table->char("area",40)->nullable();
            $table->string("address")->nullable();
            $table->char("floor",20)->nullable();
            $table->char("apart",20)->nullable();
            $table->char("gender",10)->nullable();
            $table->integer("byear")->nullable();
            $table->integer("bmonth")->nullable();
            $table->integer("bday")->nullable();
            $table->char("aphone",25)->nullable();
            $table->integer("points")->default(0);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

the PHP artisan migrate always fire these errors

> PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'bglee'")

I use the last version of laravel

the database name is correct and exist

[image]

Comment: what is the port of phpmyadmin?

Comment: Try to clear the cache before migrating: `php artisan cache:clear`

Comment: Are you using Vagrant, Homestead, or some other sort of VM?

Comment: @Laerte I cleared it -> same

Comment: @ceejayoz - No experience , I just use PHPMyAdmin

Comment: is your mysql server running ?

Comment: @Andrew yes through MAMP (free edition)

Comment: @SachinAghera 8888 , for mysql is 3306

Comment: click the mamp icon > mysql > mysql console > press enter for password > type "show databases", is it there? :D

Comment: @Andrew I can't find mysql console in MAMP (OSX)

Comment: @AboMohsen ok u could try "mamp mysql console" in google

Comment: Asssuming you're running `php artisan serve`. Stop the serve and restart and try `php artisan migrate` once again

Comment: @Option Connection Refused

Comment: @Abo, what are you using to run the site? For example: Mac's localhost or MAMP?

Comment: this is totally insane

Comment: both - the laravel website on Mac's port and MAMP to run mysql database server

Comment: the laravel website runs on Mac's localhost after using this command "php artisan serve"

Answer (score 0):

If you use vagrant than just try this step

- vagrant ssh
- cd /var/www/yourproject
- php artisan migrate

Answer (score 0):

Check whether database create or not.

And then check configuration details  and .env without trailing space .
app/config/database.php

Finally Clear cache,config and view

Comment: @AboMohsen Yes ..!  you can create  table manually and feed your data . but should create model and migrate file receptive table.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

I will not be able to explain logical reasons which made this issue occurs

I was using PhpMyAdmin through MAMP and the local host which generated from this command : `php artisan serve` - my project folder was in the desktop

now I used PhpMyAdmin through XAMPP and changed the MySQL port to 3333 and also the port variable in the .env file to 3333 , also moved the project folder to XAMPP htdocs folder .. done

Sorry - I can't understand why this issue happened